# Integral of $\operatorname{Si}(x)/(x(x^2+1))$ from $0$ to infinity

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, euler-mascheroni-constant

> Evaluate $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Si}(x)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx.$$

I use the Feynman’s technique.  Let
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Si}(ax)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx$$
then
$I'(a)=\frac{\pi}{2a}  (1-e^{-a})$. After some steps, I get:
$$I(a)=\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(a) -\frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{Ei}(-a)+C$$
Wolfram Alpha gives me the result $\frac{\pi \gamma}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{Ei}(-1)$, but I have no idea how to find the constant $C$.

$\operatorname{Si}(x)$ is the [Sine Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral),
$\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ is the [Exponential Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral),
$\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant).

Comment: 1) Please [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).
2) Isn't there a $\int$ missing in your definition of $I(a)?$

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the integral sign

Comment: What is "Si(x)"?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: what's $I(0)$? What's $\lim_{a\to0^+}(\ln a-\operatorname{Ei}(-a))$?

Answer (score 3):

The hint given by J.G. is a good one!

From the definition of $I$ we have that $\lim_{a\to 0^+}I(a)=I(0)=0$. On the other hand
$$\lim_{a\to 0^+}I(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{a\to 0^+}(\ln(a) - \operatorname{Ei}(-a))+C=\frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{a\to 0^+}(-\gamma-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{ (-a)^n}{n\cdot n!})+C=-\frac{\pi}{2}\gamma+C$$
where we used the the [power series expansion for $\operatorname{Ei}$](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1957-11-057/S0025-5718-1957-0088069-0/S0025-5718-1957-0088069-0.pdf) at $x=0$:
$$\operatorname{Ei}(x)= \gamma +\ln|x| + \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{ x^n}{n\cdot n!}.$$
Therefore $C=\frac{\pi}{2}\gamma$, and
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Si}(x)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx=I(1)=-\frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{Ei}(-1)+\frac{\pi}{2}\gamma$$
as expected. Note that the result can also be written as
$$-\frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{Ei}(-1)+\frac{\pi}{2}\gamma=\frac{\pi}{2} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n\cdot n!}\approx 1.2513.$$